# What is pitch accent for ではありません?

Tags: particles, pitch-accent, phonology, phonetics

I hear it like: ではありません{HHLHHHL}

Is it correct?

Could not find answer in OJAD.

**PRAAT:**
[image: Pitch image of ではありません voice sample]

[image: Pitch image of ではありません voice sample with hiragana]

Sound sample: https://voca.ro/1iCkbzE4w7HT

Comment: Generally the accent for the first sound of a particle depends on the preceding word (heiban or not). In this sense, the accent of で is not fixed.

Comment: As @sundowner says.  The audiograph and pitch pattern show in the OP appear to be correct for my own perception of ではありません, when used as a kind of standalone sentence in response to something said earlier.  When used as the conclusion of a sentence, the pitch pattern may vary from what is shown, depending on the prosody (musicality, if you will - the natural ups and downs of running speech) of the entire sentence.

Comment: Do you use special settings for Praat? When I try to use Praat the graph never looks this good…

Comment: She says で＼は ありませ＼ん. Note that では{HH} is impossible in Standard Japanese.

Comment: @sundowner and Eiríkr Útlendi Thank you for your replies.
So if I understood right, that 「で」and「は」are both the particles attached to the preceding word, and then comes the next word ありません?
So if the pitch of the preceding word is atamadaka, nakadaka or odaka, then では particles will have low pitch: [atamadaka word]+ではありません{LLLHHHL}.
If the pitch of the preceding word is heiban, then では particles will have high pitch:  [heiban word]+ではありません{HHLHHHL}

Comment: @firuvi Sorry, I am not sure, as it's only the second day I am using Praat, so I am newbie in this software. I also often getting some broken and ugly pitch lines in Praat, so I guess this one is just lucky voice sample case. But maybe, it worth to check the Pitch Range setting in tab [Pitch] -> [Pitch settings] -> [Pitch range (Hz)]. There is range from 75.0 Hz to 500.0 Hz by default. If you have lower Pitch range it could cause some problems with pitch line display.

Comment: @dekinai If comment by sundowner is correct, then it is possible, assuming「で」and「は」are the particles, but not the word stem. HH pitch is impossible in the beginning of the word, but in this case it is not stem of the word: [some word]+では {HH}+ありません{LHHHL}. So from this point of you では is not the beginning of word ではありません, but the particle attached to the word that comes before ありません.

Comment: は is particle, but this で should not be considered as particle. Here, で(...)ある construction (where some particles are allowed inside) is the extended copula (verb meaning "to be"), and it consists of で (earlier にて), which is 〜て form of defective simple copula *n-*, and existential verb ある "to exist". So you can consider で ある as a 2-words construction: "to be" + "to exist". The first word is the main part which gives meaning to whole construction. The second word allows to conjugate this construction, and can be considered to be auxiliary verb here.

Comment: (VERB-て ある is another construction with auxiliary verb ある.) Also compare, how in English, verb "to be" can be used as auxiliary verb, and if it was omitted, then e.g. *"he singing" is unspecified to whether it means "he is singing", "he was singing", "he will be singing" etc. In respective languages, で and "singing" give general meaning, while ある and "to be" are for conjugation.

Comment: I pronounce this way: 「[りんごではありません]{LHHHLLHHHL}」「[みかんではありません]{HLLLLLHHHL}」

Comment: @Arfrever Thank you for your comment, I'll need to learn Japanese deeper to fully understand this information.

Comment: @Chocolate thank you for your response.